# How convert Dictionary<string, List<string>> to List<string> c#?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return errors list from BadRequest in API response, but there is one adventure, errors came in response from BadRequest are in key value format json like array of objects, and myh response model is contains List. So I stored errors from badrequest in dictionary for temporary purpose but I want to store that errors in List.

```
BadRequest response:
```

```
{
  "title": "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "instance": "/api/endpoint",
  "traceId": "00-2498cc27zz278f0eca89b6786e20ee6a-768a44a9325d8956-00",
  "errors": {
    "DuplicateEmail": [
      "Email '<emailid>' is already taken."
    ],
    "DuplicateUserId": [
      "UserId '<userid>' is already taken."
    ]
  }
}
```

```
MyAPI response Model:
```

```
Class Response{
public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

//dictionary declared to storeonly errors from BadRequest response
Dictionary<string, List<string>> errs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

dynamic err = badReqResponse.Errors;

//store bad request errors to dictionary
errs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(err));


//how I returened errors in my response model
return BadRequest(new QueryResponse{IsSuccess=false,Errors = errs.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList()  <-- HERE I RETURNED KEYS FROM ERRORS IN DICTIONARY LIKE DUPLICATEEMAIL,DUPLICATEUSERID but i want to return value in the dictionary/return values.
```

c#

Comment: Firstly, don't create objects that you don't need. When you declare `errs` you create a new object and assign it to the variable, then you discard that new object when you assign a different object to the same variable immediately after. Just assign the second object without creating the first. In fact, why not wait until you've got the object you want to assign before declaring the variable, i.e. `var errs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(err));`?

Comment: There are fancier ways to do it but why not do the obvious? Create a new `List`, loop through the `Dictionary` and add the contents of each existing `List` to the new one? That's just fundamentals so there's reason you shouldn't be able to do that for yourself.

Comment: *`Errors = errs.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList()  <-- HERE I RETURNED KEYS..but i want to return value`* -  Erm... How about you Select `kvp.Value` instead ?

Comment: What is the actual type of `err`? Why are you serializing and then immediately de-serializing?